# Ansible - How to run yum upgrade with non root user?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to run `yum upgrade` using non root user by granting it privileges via `sudo` but I'm not able to make it work.

To the non root user I have given root privileges by changing `sudoers` file

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root      ALL=(ALL)       ALL
a_user    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

My Ansible playbook is as follows,

```yaml
---
- hosts: web-servers
  remote_user: mc
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: a_user
  tasks:
  - name: upgrade all packages
    yum: name=* state=latest
```

When I try the above playbook there is no error but the upgrade does not happen.

```
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.0.53]

TASK [upgrade all packages] ****************************************************
ok: [192.168.0.53]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.0.53               : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

```yaml
---
- hosts: web-servers
  remote_user: a_user
  tasks:
  - name: upgrade all packages
    yum: name=* state=latest
    become: yes
    become_method: sudo
```

And when I try to run the above playbook there is no error and the process never completes.

```
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.0.53]


TASK [upgrade all packages] ****************************************************N
```

Comment: You should try running the playbook with `-vvvv` this will give you informations on what ansible is actually running, and maybe even the reason why it's getting stuck. If you use `remote_user: mc` make sure you can sudo to `a_user`

Comment: Are you passing `--ask-become-pass` at the command line or specifying the sudo password in any other way? If not you'll need to add `NOPASSWD:ALL` to your sudoers line.

Comment: You might want to include the OS information.  If this is a RHEL system/server, you might need to make sure that a valid subscription exists before you try updating.  See the [redhat_subscription module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/redhat_subscription_module.html) in the ansible docs for that.

Answer (score 1):

> ... there is no error and the process never completes.

The task is most likely waiting for the password in the background.

Because of the entry `ALL` only and **not** `NOPASSWD: ALL` in your `sudoers` file, it would be necessary for you to provide the `sudo` password too via `--ask-become-pass`. See [Understanding privilege escalation: become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) for more background information.

Since I have same requirement in my environment I like to share my approach here.

The file `/etc/sudoers` contains

```
root                                  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
%wheel                                ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
%admin_group                          ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

and an `UPDATE_ROLE/main.yml` with

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Update all packages
    yum:
      name: '*'
      state: latest
```

On the remote host there is an `admin_user` which is member of the `admin_group`.

So with `export ADMIN_USER="admin_user"` either

```
sshpass -p ${PASSWORD} ansible-playbook --user ${ADMIN_USER} --ask-pass UPDATE_ROLE/main.yml
```

or an ad-hoc command

```
sshpass -p ${PASSWORD} ansible test --user ${ADMIN_USER} --ask-pass --become --module-name shell --args 'yum --assumeyes update'
```

will work.